# multiple file upload with jquery with limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I am trying to find a solution with a multiple file upload with a limit.

I have created this fiddle to show what I have in mind.

http://jsfiddle.net/8MzNs/

with the HTML inside my form

```
<ul id="file-list">
    <li class="file-box">Image 1</li>
    <li class="file-box">Image 2</li>
    <li class="file-box">Image 3</li>
    <li class="file-box">Image 4</li>
    <li class="file-box">Image 5</li>
</ul>
```

instead of:

```
<input type="file" name="file-1" />
<input type="file" name="file-2" />
<input type="file" name="file-3" />
<input type="file" name="file-4" />
<input type="file" name="file-5" />
```

But I cannot find a solution with a limit like this. But I might have missed it.

Comment: Are you trying to do something similar to what Facebook does while uploading multiple image files?

Comment: Not entirely. I will have a maximum of 5 images to be uploaded, listed like my first HTML example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed Uploadify which works perfect and then I will add a small script (jQuery/PHP) that will display the images as they are added.